# install mysql-client-5.7 on debian buster

Tags: debian, mysql, apt

I would like to know how can I install `mysql-client-5.7` on debian buster using apt-get since it is not already present in `Debian Buster Package Repository`?

Some Background info:

I want to install `mysql-client-5.7` on AWS Codebuild (remote server) which I can't SSH into so the only way I can install it there is using apt-get commands.

Comment: Do you specifically need version 5.7?

Comment: yes as I want to tie my sql server 5.7 community addition with it.

Answer (score 23):

Debian stopped packaging mysql-client as of buster. You can use [`apt-get install default-mysql-client`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/default-mysql-client) which will install mariadb-client-10.3. MariaDB is a fork of MySQL. The client can still be started with the command `mysql`, and the documentation for it is [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysql-command-line-client/). This client *should* still work fine for MySQL Server 5.7.

For a full list of differences, you can compare [mysql-client-5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html) and  [mariadb-client](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysql-command-line-client/).

If you really still desire mysql-client-5.7, you'll either have to manually install it, or look for a PPA that has it packaged.

Comment: Mysqldump which ships with mariadb-client 10.3 doesn't seem to work with mysql-5.7 since while making dump it issues command `Show Package Status` which is not a MySql command but a MariaDB command.

Comment: with sid (currently unstable) mysql-client will come back in version 5.7 (also 5.5) as well as default-mysql-client will be continued. Source: https://packages.debian.org/de/sid/mysql-client-5.7

Comment: Seems your link is dead, @Spears

Comment: They categoized it under "database" and the current version as of today is 8.0.x. Here the actual link to the package: https://packages.debian.org/sid/database/mysql-client and the link the version 8:
https://packages.debian.org/sid/mysql-client-8.0